# Using jq to load one json file into the hash of another json file

Tags: json, merge, jq

I'm trying to figure out how to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to load the content of one json file into the hash of another file. E.g.:

this file:

```
{
  "annotations": {...},
  "rows": [ {...}, {...}]
}
```

should be inserted into this file at the hash dashboard:

```
{
  "dashboard": { },
  "overwrite": true,
  "message": "new commit"
}
```

so the resulting file should be

```
{
  "dashboard": {
     "annotations": {...},
     "rows": [ {...}, {...}]
  },
  "overwrite": true,
  "message": "new commit"
}
```

I was thinking to do it with an pipe | or |= operator but I can't figure out how to use one content and assign it  to a select filter of the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jq** solution:

```
jq --slurpfile annot annot.json '.dashboard |= $annot[0]' dashb.json
```

> `--slurpfile variable-name filename`:
>
> This option reads all the JSON texts in the named file and binds an
>   array of the parsed JSON values to the given global variable.

Comment: The --slurpfile option is what I needed, had to update jq then it was rather obvious! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your jq does not have --slurpfile, then you could, for example, run jq as follows:

```
jq -s '.[0] as $fragment | .[1] | (.dashboard |= $fragment)' fragment.json dashboard.json
```

Comment: Not a bad idea either to do it that way.